# Possibilities of Fingerprint Issue in WebRTC

Tags: ios, webrtc, sdp, apprtcdemo

I am testing WebRTC implementation with Apprtc demo for iOS

I am facing a issue where the fingerprint does not match in the local sdp we send.

```
Failed to set session description. 
Error: Error Domain=RTCSDPError Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (RTCSDPError error -1.)" 
UserInfo=0x17466d480 {
    error=Failed to set local answer 
          sdp: Failed to push down transport 
          description: Local fingerprint does not match identity. 
          Expected: sha-1 FB:05:7C:59:1A:57:A2:47:0D:E2:2A:02:D1:C6:21:F9:9B:9A:10:0E 
          Got: sha-1 92:1C:6B:E0:2F:CA:63:49:8C:F4:CC:C2:F4:B9:86:F5:D8:7F:56:CC}
```

Can you please suggest what might be the reason behind this issue or where to debug in Apprtc

Comment: I am getting same issue. Have u find any solution for this..?

Comment: Nope :(... Will try and post my solution here when i find the answer. Please post yours if you find it

Comment: Sure..R u developing video chat application..? May I know which sample app r u testing for video chat using webrtc?

Comment: It was found that the same project contains two SRTP libraries. When removing one everything was working fine.